# How can I view which of my SSH keys a DigitalOcean VPS can use?

Tags: digitalocean

I created a droplet/VPS.

How can I view which of my SSH keys a VPS can use?

I added some SSH keys to my DigitalOcean account.

I created a droplet, I don't recall which SSH keys I clicked the checkboxes for, for it to have access to.

How can I check?

At the moment the SSH key that I thought I'd "checked"/clicked the checkbox for the VPS to use, isn't letting me in.  So I can't access my VPS.

Comment: turned out I made the classic error of forgetting that ssh assumes the username of the local account exists on the remote machine..  A digitalocean VPS only has a root account.. and the SSH key is added to ` /root/.ssh/authorized_keys`  so you have to go in with `root@ip` rather than just ip so  e.g.  `ssh root@ip`    And I think once the VPS is created then you are meant to be able to get into it and then it's all just normal SSH methods for adding SSH keys, in order to add any other SSH keys e.g. ssh-copy-id

Answer (score 0):

Check that you specified the username when you SSH in, otherwise SSH assumes that the username you are logging into the remote machine as, exists on the local machine. A digitalocean "droplet"(VPS), will have one user, Root. So you have to do ssh root@ip to get in.  Not specifying the username is a classic error people make with SSH.

If you really can't log into it then would have to create another "droplet"/VPS, and may as well destroy that one that you can't get into. (destroying any droplet you aren't using 'cos they charge you for any droplets)

When creating the digitalocean hosted VPS, in the digitalocean web interface to create the VPS, you either specify that root will log in via a password, or via an SSH key.   After that, you don't get that interface again.  If you want to then see what SSH keys you can get in with you'd have to SSH in and `cat /root/.ssh/authorized_keys`.   Once That VPS is created, then any amendments re SSH keys in relation to that VPS, is done via standard SSH methods like `ssh-copy-id`. Not a digitalocean web interface.

Also, note that the "name" that digitalocean asks you to give for an SSH key has no technical ramifications, so good to name it with a name/description that tells you something of where the SSH key is located.

As for what SSH keys you can add to a VPS when creating it.. it's good to have in the 'web browser', a bookmarks folder, with some bookmarks for areas of digitalocean like droplets list, snapshots, community forum, and ssh keys. This is one for the SSH keys https://cloud.digitalocean.com/account/security  (though not particular to any one VPS).

Comment: I suppose If you wanted to do things a bit more manually you could choose to log into root with a password, then set up the SSH server yourself.